# Find the value of angle using elementary geometry rules

Tags: geometry, triangles, plane-geometry, angle

In $\triangle ABC$ with base $AC$, $\angle C$ = $46^\circ$ and $AC$ is extended to point $D$.

$E$ is a point on $AB$ and $DE$ is joined.
[image]

> Given that $AB=AD=DE$. Find $\angle ABC$.

Comment: What it lacks I have attached an image of question

Comment: What @James pointed out is that you did not say what you have difficulty with. What have you tried? Is there some step you are stuck on? Does the answer that you get does not make sense? Please let us know, so we can help.

Comment: This is silly! The figure is impossible as it is drawn - you cannot have C between A and D, and E between A and B, and AD=AD=DE, and angle C = 46 deg.

Comment: @Andrei I have tried with extra construction and used the isocles triangle property as well as constructing a equilateral triangle to get something but I am unable to figure out the answer.

Comment: @almagest you mean Question is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** you will need to use the following:

- The sum of the angles on a straight line equal $180^\circ$.
- The sum of the angles in a triangle is $180^\circ$.
- In a isosceles triangle, the two base angles are the same.

For example, find $\angle BCD$ from the first hint, and $\angle BAC$ from the second. Continue writing all angles in terms of $x$ and $46^\circ$. At some point, you will get an equation relating the two.

Comment: I think you have fallen into a trap. The figure is not possible as drawn.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, C lies between A and D, and E lies between A and B. But that is impossible. If you allow D to lie between A and C, or E to lie outside the segment AB, then $\angle ABC$ is not determined.

[image]

[image]